# How to fix objects (text fields, labels, etc) in viewcontroller.xib (Xcode 4)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator, viewcontroller

Sorry I am just learning how to program so sorry for the noob question. I began playing around with Xcode and put together my first test app with just a login and password. The problem I am having is that what is shown in the ViewController.xib screen looks perfectly fine as far as layout. The objects are exactly where I want them to be. However, when I run the simulator, the textfields and labels move around! How can I get it so that exactly what is shown on the ViewController.xib comes up in the simulator? Thanks!

Here is what it looks like from my ViewController.xib screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT6pM.png

And here is what outputs in the simulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U18Rj.png

Comment: There's a little switch at the bottom right of the Storyboard editor (and I'm sure the xib editor as well) that lets you switch between the iPhone 5 size and iPhone 4 size. You should check this to make sure that's not what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by autolayout. If you don't want to learn about it (yet), click on a view in interface builder and in right side panel under first tab uncheck "Use autolayout".